# flex4: loading flex4 swf using swfloader shows only the loading bar

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flex4, swfloader

I try to load an swf in my flex 4 project using the following line of code:

```
<mx:SWFLoader id="game_swf"  source="demo.swf" complete="init()" />
```

the demo.swf file is another project i created using flex 4. the problem is that when i run the application i see only the loading bar of the demo.swf flash file and nothing else.

if i try to load a different swf file (for a example a game i downloaded), it loads just fine.

what am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this happens only when i use the debug version of the swf, when i created a release build and used it instead it worked.

Comment: Problem does not occur in the final version of flex 4.